# how to pass EOF as an offset while reading a binary file using python?

Tags: python-2.7, file

I have a binary file. Now, I am trying to write some values from a particular offset till the EOF. I wrote a method to do that but not sure how to pass the EOF as an offset. I am trying to have a method where I can pass the starting offset and the end offset. Here I want the end offset can be either an address or EOF. How to pass the EOF as an offset to my method? for example my start is 129 and end is EOF or offset like 1129?

```
def writeValues(start, end=0):
    try:
        with open("current.xof", "r+b") as f:            
            for i in xrange(start, end+1):#write the data
                f.seek(i)            
                f.write("\xAA")           #write data
    except IOError:
        print("Error file not found")
```

Also, while writing to the binary file, I am ending up writing the Char values instead of hex values. So to fix that I tried a solution but not satisfied with that. I feel there should be an easier way to do that.

```
def updateChecksum(checksum, start, end):
    '''update the checksum in bytes start - end'''
    checksumList= (' '.join(checksum[i: i+2] for i in xrange(0,len(checksum), 2)))
    checksumArr=checksumList.split(" ")

    count  = start

    with open("current.xof", "r+b") as f:
          for i in range(0,len(checksumArr)):
              f.seek(count)
              count  =  count + 1
              f.write('%c' %(int(checksumArr[i], 16)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `end == 0` as a sentinel value meaning EOF, and interpret it yourself.

```
def writeValues(start, end=0):
    try:
        with open("current.xof", "r+b") as f:            
            for i in xrange(start, end+1):
                if i == 0:
                    f.seek(0, 2)  # 2 means seek from EOF
                else:
                    f.seek(i)            
                f.write("\xAA")           #write data
    except IOError:
        print("Error file not found")
```

> I am ending up writing the Char values instead of hex values.

I'm not sure what this means. `'\xaa'` should print the byte 0xAA

```
>>> print '\x21'
!
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I invoke the method writeValues(129, 1129) how i will become 0?

Comment: @hago Im not sure what you mean. If you pass a non-zero end offset, it will not become zero. But if instead of 1129, you want the write to the end of the file, you can call writeValues(129, 0)

Comment: when I invoke the method writeValues(129,0) then, the for loop will iterate from 129 to 0 which means there will be an empty list. So the control will never reach if i==0. So the solution you suggested is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the code like below and got it working. Is there any way to improve this?

```
def writeValues(start, end=0):
    try:
        with open("current.xof", "r+b") as f:
            if end == 0:
                f.seek(0,2)
                end_position = f.tell() #get the end position of the file
                print(end_position)
                for i in xrange(start, end_position+1):
                    f.seek(i)
                    f.write("\x00")
    except IOError:
        print("Error file not found")
```